# Hacer girar una imagen en Mobile con Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, phonegap, jquery-mobile

estoy intentanto lograr que una imagen (particularmente una ruleta), gire mediante css/javascript, para una aplicacion hecha en Jquery mobile y empaquetada en phonegap.
Con el codigo que tengo, en pc, gira perfectamente, pero a la hora de instalarla en el celular, no lo hace. Alguna solucion? 
Les dejo el codigo:

```js
var imgruleta = document.getElementById('imgruleta');
girar.on('tap', function() {
 girar.hide();
   imgruleta.style.animationName = '';
   setTimeout(function(){
    imgruleta.className = 'hacergirar';
    imgruleta.style.transform = 'rotate(8000deg)';
    /*imgruleta.style.animationName = 'girar';*/},500)
 if(!primeraEjecucion){
  resultado.text('');
 }
 primeraEjecucion = false;
 cont++;
 var pos;
 do{
  pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * vComidas.length);
 }while(pos == actual || pos == 0)
 actual = pos;
 verIngr.hide();
 setTimeout(function() {
  resultado.text(vComidas[pos].plato);
  resultado.show(); 
  girar.show()
  girar.val("Girar de nuevo!");
  girar.button("refresh");
  imgruleta.style.transform = '';
  imgruleta.className = '';

  $('#ver main').html('');
  
  if(vComidas[pos].ingredientes.length > 0){
   verIngr.show();
   var h3= $('<h3></h3>');
   h3.text(vComidas[pos].plato);
   $('#ver main').append(h3);
   var divlista = $('<div id="divingr" data-role="listview"></div>');
   var p;
   var hr;
   /*var ul = $('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
   var li;*/
   for(var i in vComidas[pos].ingredientes)
   {
    p = $('<p class="listaingr"></p>');
    p.text(vComidas[pos].ingredientes[i]);
    hr = $('<hr />');
    divlista.append(p);
    divlista.append(hr);
   }
   $('#ver main').append(divlista);
   //divlista('refresh');
   div.listview().listview('refresh');
  }
  else{
   verIngr.hide();
  }
    },5500);
 
});
```

```css
.hacergirar{
 transition: 5s cubic-bezier(.31,.89,.49,.99);
}
```

```html
   <main role="main" class="ui-content" >
 <img src="recursos/imagenes/ruleta2.png" alt="ruleta decididora" id="imgruleta" />
 <p id="platoelegido"></p>
 <input type="button" value="Girar!" />
 <a href="#ver" id="veringr" data-role="button" data-iconshadow="false">Ver ingredientes</a>
 </main>
```

Comment: Disculpa, dice que `girar` no esta definido, si miras tu mismo ejemplo aqui en la pagina te aparece

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, pude replicar tu ejemplo, y pude ver que la funcion `girar` la estas invocando, pero no esta creada, tampoco se por que usas ese `girar.hide()`, ya que tampoco veo ese método, de igual forma aquí te dejo la imagen girando.

```js
var imgruleta = document.getElementById('imgruleta');
var btn_girar = document.getElementById('btn_girar');

btn_girar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    girar();
});

function girar(){
  
  imgruleta.style.animationName = '';
   setTimeout(function(){
    imgruleta.className = 'hacergirar';
    imgruleta.style.transform = 'rotate(8000deg)';
    /*imgruleta.style.animationName = 'girar';*/},500)
 if(!primeraEjecucion){
  resultado.text('');
 }
 primeraEjecucion = false;
 cont++;
 var pos;
 do{
  pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * vComidas.length);
 }while(pos == actual || pos == 0)
 actual = pos;
 verIngr.hide();
 setTimeout(function() {
  resultado.text(vComidas[pos].plato);
  resultado.show(); 
  girar.show()
  girar.val("Girar de nuevo!");
  girar.button("refresh");
  imgruleta.style.transform = '';
  imgruleta.className = '';

  $('#ver main').html('');
  
  if(vComidas[pos].ingredientes.length > 0){
   verIngr.show();
   var h3= $('<h3></h3>');
   h3.text(vComidas[pos].plato);
   $('#ver main').append(h3);
   var divlista = $('<div id="divingr" data-role="listview"></div>');
   var p;
   var hr;
   /*var ul = $('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
   var li;*/
   for(var i in vComidas[pos].ingredientes)
   {
    p = $('<p class="listaingr"></p>');
    p.text(vComidas[pos].ingredientes[i]);
    hr = $('<hr />');
    divlista.append(p);
    divlista.append(hr);
   }
   $('#ver main').append(divlista);
   //divlista('refresh');
   div.listview().listview('refresh');
  }
  else{
   verIngr.hide();
  }
    },5500);
 

}
```

```css
.hacergirar{
 transition: 5s cubic-bezier(.31,.89,.49,.99);
}
```

```html
<main role="main" class="ui-content" >
 <img src="recursos/imagenes/ruleta2.png" alt="ruleta decididora" id="imgruleta" />
 <p id="platoelegido"></p>
 <input type="button" value="Girar!" id="btn_girar" />
 <a href="#ver" id="veringr" data-role="button" data-iconshadow="false">Ver ingredientes</a>
 </main>
```

Comment: Gracias, la imagen ya giraba perfectamente, el problema era que lo estaba testeando en una versión vieja de android y no lo reconocía. Testee el mismo código en una versión mas nueva y anduvo a la perfección. Desde ya muchas gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Me alegra, siempre es bueno probar las cosas en diferentes versiones, ya que eso puede ser un problema, lo mismo es a la hora de probar una pagina, hay que hacerlo en varios navegadores.